# Possibility to apply Conditional Access Policy to MS Teams custom app

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

We have a custom app in MS Teams. But we do not want to enable this app to entire Organization. Currently we have setup a custom policy in Teams Admin Center, added the custom app to the Policy and updated the User Policies to the custom policy for the users who need access to the app.

Is there any possibility to restrict access to the custom app through Azure AD Conditional Access policies instead of creating a custom policy in Teams Admin Center? I have tried to search with the app-id of the custom app in Azure AD and couldn't find anything to setup a conditional access policy. The users list is dynamic and will gets updated frequently, is there is any way we can achieve this.

I do not want the user to add the app from Teams and they show a message saying -"you cant access the app ". If possible I would like to setup a conditional policy such that the app wont be visible in the Teams Apps Viewer even after the app is enabled in Organization policy.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the policies for specific users in your organization. You can then use [app permission policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-permission-policies), [app setup policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-setup-policies), and [custom app policies and settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-custom-app-policies-and-settings) to configure the app experience for specific users in your organization. Please  check this [Manage app permission policies in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-permission-policies)  & [Manage your apps in the Microsoft Teams admin center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-apps) for more info.

Comment: Hi Nikitha, Thank you for the response. But I am looking for options other than creating a custom Policy. Whenever we want to enable the custom app to new users, we had to update the user's policy from Admin Center. As the app increases, this would result in having more number of users in a custom policy rather than Org-wide policy. So I am looking for other options like setting up a Conditional access policy for Azure AD apps. Is this possible for Teams custom apps ?